# Magento debug installation/upgrade process

Tags: magento

I'm trying to upgrade Magento from 1.3.2.4 to 1.8 but finally browser reset the connection so I even cannot see what is the reason of the problem. How can I debug installation process, so I will be able to see what modules were installed/upgraded, to what version, what module is installing currently now, etc. I think that the best way is some kind of install log that is written to file. May be someone has some scripts or can suggest me classes/method where I can put log file write points?

Comment: check system log file

Comment: it is empty. log folder even does not exist